# PHPExcel Erroring After Server Upgrade?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I'm a little lost here and didn't know where else to go so I thought best place to ask would be here... So, I recently upgraded my site's server from shared to VPS after which I attempted to download an Excel report from my DB like I usually would do regularly. However, since the upgrade after I download it, I get an error when opening the documents; it gives me the option to still open it but it is clearly corrupt or something. I have attempted to debug this issue but I am most definitely struggling with this one. I've also made sure I'm using the most recent version of PHPExcel but sadly this didn't resolve it. The error I'm experiencing is as follows:

> The file format and extension of "myReportName.xls" does not match.

If anyone can shed a little light on what might be going on here I'd really appreciate it, and thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I don't think this would affect it, but I thought I'd add I also had a bug with my DB after the upgrade where nothing would insert due to fields not having a default value. They worked fine on the shared server but on the VPS I had to edit all my columns to have a default value of null. Also in case someone asks I didn't think it was necessary to post my code as it was working fine before the server upgrade so I thought the bug wasn't there, but if I'm wrong feel free to let me know.

Comment: Why you're still using ``PHPExcel`` when it's not maintained any longer. Make sure you have ``php: ^5.2|^7.0``, ``ext-mbstring``, ``ext-xml``, ``ext-xmlwriter`` modules installed on your server. || Suggestion, use ``PHPSpreadsheet `` https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet.

Comment: Re your update...it's unclear, do you still have a bug now, or not? If not then please just delete the question. Also, where exactly are you seeing this error? Is it when you try to open the file in Excel? Maybe the file is really an XLSX, or a CSV, or something?